# In the definition of a monoidal category, how are the natural isomorphisms natural transformations?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, functors

Categories for the Working Mathematician says:

> Formally, a  monoidal category  $B =  (B, *, e,  \alpha,\lambda,
>  \rho)$  is  a category $B$,  a  bifunctor  $*: B \times B \to B$,  an 
>   object  $e \in  B$,  and  three  natural  isomorphisms  $\alpha,
>  \lambda, \rho$.  Explicitly,
>
> $$ \alpha = \alpha_{a,b,c} : a * (b*c) \equiv (a*b)*c$$
>
> is natural for all $a, b, c \in B$, and $\lambda$ and $\rho$ are
>   natural
>
> $$ \lambda_a: e * a \equiv a$$  $$\rho_a: a*e \equiv a$$
>
> for all objects $a \in B$, and
>
> $$\lambda_e = \rho_e: e * e \to e.$$

$\alpha, \lambda, \rho$ are natural  isomorphisms, so they should be natural transformations between functors.  But I have difficulty understand they are natural transformations based on how they are used in the definition of a monoidal category above.

- From what functors to what functors are $\alpha, \lambda, \rho$ respectively?
- By the definition of a natural transformation, what are the morphisms which $\alpha, \lambda, \rho$ assign to each object respectively?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your second question; the morphisms $\lambda$ (for instance) assigns to each $a$ is $\lambda_a$. If you're asking how this morphism is defined, that's going to depend on the particular monoidal category; there's no general answer to that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\alpha$ goes from $-*(-*-)$ to $(-*-)*-$ : these are functors $B^3\to B$, the first one is defined by $(a,b,c)\mapsto a*(b*c)$ and the second one similarly, and on maps well it is defined in the obvious way, knowing that $*: B^2\to B$ is a functor.

$\lambda$ goes from $e*-$ to $id_B$, and similarly for $\rho$

Their specific nature/values depend on the monoidal category in question. If it is a *strict* monoidal category for instance, they will be the identity. If not, they can be all sorts of things.